# Java8 boolean post unary operator

Tags: java, boolean-operations

Does Java 8 have a post unary operator for primitive booleans?

```
int a = 1;
a++; //look at then increment

boolean bool = true;
???
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such operator.

Even the `!` isn't doing the same as `++` does with numeric types:

- `++` *updates* a *variable* (or array element);
- `!` negates the value of an *expression*. If applied to a variable, the variable's value is unchanged.

The most similar thing to a "negate operator" would be

```
(aBoolean ^= true)
```

but this is "pre-negate", rather than "post-negate".

You can contrive a "post-negate operator" using non-short circuiting operators:

```
(aBoolean | ((aBoolean ^= true) & false)
```

But really: don't do this. It's baffling.